# Candidate constructor not viable when std::vector::push_back()

Tags: c++

I am not sure why, but when I do `vec.push_back(tc2);` I get three different instances of `candidate constructor not viable:`.

However, the code runs fine without the line `vec.push_back(tc2)`. Why is that?

````
#include <vector> 

class TestClass
{
private:
    std::string url_;
    std::string name_;
    long long size_;

public:
    TestClass(std::string url, std::string name, long long size)
        : url_{url}, name_{name}, size_{size} {}

    TestClass() : TestClass{"", "", -1} {}

    TestClass(TestClass &source)
        : url_(source.getUrl()),
          name_(source.getName()),
          size_(source.getSize()) {}

    std::string getUrl() const;

    std::string getName() const;

    long long getSize() const;
};

std::string TestClass::getUrl() const{
    return url_; 
}

std::string TestClass::getName() const{
    return name_; 
}

long long TestClass::getSize() const {
    return size_; 
}

int main()
{
    TestClass tc{};
    TestClass tc2{"a", "b", 222};


    std::vector<TestClass> vec; 
    vec.push_back(tc2);

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `TestClass(TestClass &source)` --> `TestClass(const TestClass &source)`

Comment: Amazing catch, thanks!

Comment: From the duplicate, I would suspect that the `vector` class uses temporaries of your object, thus it could not use the copy constructor without it using a `const` object.